# I want to tag users in a leaderboard, but instead it tags their id

Tags: javascript, discord, leaderboard

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for my discord bot, and so far it works, but whenever I want to tag players in the embed it just sends something like this <@90258560912791> instead of: @wex

Here's my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}btop`)) {
  if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Walls")) {
    var description = ""
    let all = `SELECT userid , points FROM bufferpoints ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10;`
    db.all(all, (err, row) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const topembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF760B')
        .setTitle(message.guild.name + "'s TOP Buffercheckers!")
        .setTimestamp()
      let i = 0;
      row.forEach(function(row) {
        i++;
        if (row.points === 0) {
          return;
        }
        description += ` ${i}. <@${row.userid}>` + `** - ${row.points}**\n`
      })

      topembed.setDescription(description)
      message.channel.send(topembed)
    })
  }
}
```

And this is what I'm getting right now if somebody wondered

[image: 1]]

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: You're getting userid instead of name when you use: <@${row.userid}> ? Perhaps there's row.username in the data that might do what you want?

Comment: Maybe the property userid that you're referring to is wrong - is there a username row.username property ?

Comment: @Andrew There's only userid which is users id and points which is self-explanatory

Comment: Looks like you'll need to look up the name then. GET/users/{user.id}
Returns a user object for a given user ID. (https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user)

Comment: @Andrew Do you suggest me to use their username?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. When I saved userid I used `message.author.id`. I changed it to `message.author.toString()`. Bot saves data as <@125512> and then tags a user in the leaderboard.